# Importing variable from another file into route file of node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm attempting to pass a prompt box variable into my route file of a node.js application, but I'm having issues having the variable be recognized.  The main prompt variable "test" is in a javascript file called mainclient.js, and I'm attempting to get it into my index.js file.  I've attempted to export it as so:
In mainclient.js I have:

```
exports.Test = test;
```

and in my index.js, I've included:

```
var mainclient = require('../public/javascripts/mainclient');
```

and then call it by using:

```
var prompt = mainclient.test;
```

When I attempt to start the node, I'm getting an error stating:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Due to the first line in my mainclient.js file being:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Anyone know a way to get this error corrected or another way that I can get the variable from mainclient.js into index.js?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:
I should add, I've attempted to import jquery in both files by including the proper header link,however, I then get an error stating:
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when attempting to start the node.  jquery is imported in the main.js file for the node though.

Comment: include jquery in your project...

Comment: I've edited the post to add more information about when I attempted to add jquery.

Comment: You are exporting `Test` but using `test`.  If that doesn't fix your issue, please provide more information.